# Does early adoption of adding "Aura local ID's" to element attributes make for more Automation friendly, Lightning components?

Tags: unit-test, automation, architecture, app-development, selenium

My company is migrating to Salesforce and the automation team wants the ability to use Java Selenium baked in. Will the system-wide inclusion of Aura Local IDs (as related to Component ID's [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm)) instead of or inclusive to standard Global IDs make the Lightning application easier and more reliable for Selenium locators to be generated?

Comment: You should consider adopting [UTAM](https://utam.dev/) since Salesforce provide the page objects for standard Salesforce page objects (components and the like), protecting you from changes that are made to how they structure these aspects. You then only need create your own page objects that represent your components then write your tests using these page objects.

Comment: Thanks, Phil but that looks like an altogether forked approach. Im just inquiring if anyone has had real-world success with Aura Id's improvement automation efficiencies.

Comment: That is why it was a comment not an answer. Yes, clearly I am suggesting an alternative approach. One that Salesforce themselves are using and supporting to help remove problems with tests being broken every time they change structuring.

Comment: BTW, [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2023/05/base-lightning-component-internal-dom-structure-changes-for-future-native-shadow-support) could be a good read and provide more reason to adopt UTAM instead of trying to use CSS selectors to locate elements in the page.

Comment: Thanks again Phil for the perspectives on UTAM. I do however still want to know if anyone has had real-world experience with Aura Local IDs.